# Problem after mounting a new SSD in a machine with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssd, migration

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a standalone machine with ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed tensorflow for studying Deep learning programming and everything was working fine.

Recently, I wanna expand the storage of my computer so I bought a 1T Kingston SSD. I migrated home/ from the old SSD to the new one and mounted the new home/ folder through following the steps at the link:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/

However, after mounting the new SSD (with home/ copied to the new SSD), I failed to launch Jupyter notebook from Terminal. I also couldn't access the previously installed programs/ packages. Everything seems going wrong. I guess the system doesn't know where to look for the installed programs. Could anyone would advise to me how to fix this problem. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the programs have problem all from snap?

Comment: Apart from snap, I noticed that even setting of CUDA environment was missing.

Comment: For snap troubleshooting, it can only access /home, and not symbolic link, make sure that you mount at /home, not symbolic to it first.

Comment: Thanks for your advice